# Nagios Webinterface Log History (No history information was found for this host in this archived log file)

Tags: ubuntu, logging, archive, nagios

I noticed that our Nagios Webinterface is not displaying the log archive/history properly, it does not show the daily logs... instead it displays sometimes 2 weeks as one log, sometimes 10 days and so on.

in the nagios.cfg the log roatation is set to daily, and it creates the daily logs of the past in the /usr/local/nagios/var/archives directory...

i can open them and read that they are not empty, but on the webinterface i get that error "No history information was found for this host in this archived log file"

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and Nagios Core 4.3.2

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Your webserver's user do not have necessary permission to read this files. You should verify it.

Comment: the permissions are set to 644, the problem is that i can see some of the logs, i.e. i can see the logs from 07-30-219 but not from today or from 08-01-2019...
EDIT: in the log 07-30-2019 i can see the logs from today... but only on the webinterface, the log files on the server are all correct